# Show error around radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

The Jquery Validation plugin docs say you can validate that at least one radio button is selected.  However, when trying to do so with some extra layout, I am not getting the error highlighting.

[image]

My code looks like this.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px;">
    <label for="factorSelect" class="control-label col-sm-3">Please select a recovery method</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
        </span>
        <div class="form-control" style="height:auto;">
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="noBold-text" style="font-size: 1em">
                    <input id="factorSelect_email" name="factorSelect" type="radio" value="EMAIL" />Send me an email
                    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-circle"></i></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="noBold-text" style="font-size: 1em">
                    <input id="factorSelect_sms" name="factorSelect" type="radio" value="SMS" />Send an SMS to my phone
                    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-circle"></i></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#forgotPasswordForm").validate({
    rules: {
        fpUsername: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        factorSelect: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        fpUsername: {
            required: "Please enter your username or email",
            minlength: "Your username must be at least {0} characters"
        },
        factorSelect: {
            required: "You must select a recovery method"
        },
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents(".form-group").addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents(".form-group").addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
    },
});
```

The has-error class never gets applied to the radio button group.

Comment: Where's the JS specifying the validation rules? (Hopefully looks something like [this example](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#example:-makes-the-gender-radio-buttons-required))

Comment: @heybignick I added the validation script.

Comment: I tried your code in my project. It's working perfectly.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I'm puzzled how it works for you. You are seeing the radio buttons in red and the error message below it?

Comment: yes..the error messsage is visible in red coloured fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error you have in [**this CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wqNMOO)...

The error message produced by jQuery Validate is positionned right after the invalid element... Which is the default.

Now you can position that error message elsewhere, using [`errorPlacement`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement).

In this [**Solution**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wqNMVb), I just placed it right after the parent `.input-group`. I'm sure that is the puzzle piece you where looking for.
;)

```
errorPlacement: function(errorLabel, invalidElement){
  if( $(invalidElement).is("[type='radio']") ){
    var inputGroup = $(invalidElement).closest(".input-group");
    inputGroup.after(errorLabel);
  }
},
```

---

**EDIT**

With your full code, that is easier to work... 
;)

The default behavior of a `button` in a `form` is to submit ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), see "type").
So if the `type` is omitted, that is what it does.

And the `.validate()` function isn't triggered by a `button type="button"`.

So...
You have to prevent the default `submit` in order to validate first.
Then, submit if the form is valid.

This is achieved by [`.preventDault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and [`submitHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)

```
$("#forgotPasswordForm").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default form submit (Have to validate first!)
})
  .validate({

    // Skipping some lines here...

    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();  // Submits only if the form is valid
  }
});
```

[**Updated CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WEPzvR?editors=1010)

Comment: Still no good.  I however might have spotted an issue.  Your button is a generic tag and your sample works.  However, as soon as I add type="button", your sample stops working.  Obviously the form is not submitting so no validation is triggered.  Maybe something?

Comment: This pen works, almost... now it does not show the error text for the text field.  https://codepen.io/SBACDeCinko/pen/qXgpXa  And something is still off as I copy this to my full page and it still fails.

Comment: Modified your code as it was not showing the message for the text field.  https://codepen.io/SBACDeCinko/pen/qXgpXa  But something is still off as I copy this to my full page and it still fails.  It smells like a conflict but I am not finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it.  Thank you for the help above with the placement of the error message.  That was not my initial issue but did come up once I got the error to display at all.  Your fix works great.

My primary issue turned out to be a CSS conflict with some styles that turn the radio buttons into pretty font-awesome icons.  The little snippet that hides the default radio buttons causes the validation to fail as it must only look for visible fields.  I set the height to zero instead and so far it seems to work.

```
.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"],
.radio label input[type="radio"] {
    /*display: none;*/
    height:0;
}
```